# Download pdf from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to download this file by API call in browser for example.
The link is : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payflows-4853a.appspot.com/o/5Q7mZB4DB2KRtKZjZx14%2Finvoices%2Fyou-x-ventures-Kt-E_Qq8DW4-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=0ab79473-a4c3-4386-b6eb-afa03fd92151

Anyone an idea how to download a file ? I tried multiple things, but none are working. Is is possible to download this image?

```
const downloadFile = async (req, res, next) => {
    let d = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payflows-4853a.appspot.com/o/5Q7mZB4DB2KRtKZjZx14%2Finvoices%2Fyou-x-ventures-Kt-E_Qq8DW4-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=0ab79473-a4c3-4386-b6eb-afa03fd92151";
 return res.download(d);
};
```

But i'm receiving the following error:

{"status":404,"error":{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"/Users/wouter/Documents/WouterGerrits/payflows_master/payflowsapp/functions/https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payflows-4853a.appspot.com/o/5Q7mZB4DB2KRtKZjZx14%2Finvoices%2Fyou-x-ventures-Kt-E_Qq8DW4-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=0ab79473-a4c3-4386-b6eb-afa03fd92151","expose":false,"statusCode":404,"status":404},"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/wouter/Documents/Wout/test_master/app/functions/https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payflows-4853a.appspot.com/o/5Q7mZB4DB2KRtKZjZx14%2Finvoices%2Fyou-x-ventures-Kt-E_Qq8DW4-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=0ab79473-a4c3-4386-b6eb-afa03fd92151'","stack":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/wouter/Documents/Wout/test_master/app/functions/https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payflows-4853a.appspot.com/o/5Q7mZB4DB2KRtKZjZx14%2Finvoices%2Fyou-x-ventures-Kt-E_Qq8DW4-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=0ab79473-a4c3-4386-b6eb-afa03fd92151'"}

Comment: Just use a normal HTTP library to download the contents of that URL.  It doesn't matter at all that it comes from Cloud Storage.

Comment: But how to return the file so it's showed in chrome's downloads for example? I'm using the firebase functions so I don't want to store the file as temp file.

Comment: If you have another question, you should post it separately.

Comment: This question is still under the same question I guess.